# Did we just go Public Beta?

Tags: discussion, public-beta

I just noticed that our [privilege requirements](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) changed to those of a public beta site. Did we just graduate to public beta?

Comment: Yes you did. We really have to add some animated fireworks or something to the home page for this. Congrats!!!

Comment: @RobertCartaino Wow, after only six days, I thought a week was minimum?

Comment: One week *is* normal (assuming everything goes well). We typically start our private beta reviews on Monday shooting for a Tuesday launch. We reviewed (and approved) the site earlier today. The only unusual action was getting everything together to launch quicker than normal. But it proceeded pretty much as expected otherwise.

Comment: Congratulations to all of you!! :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess we did. Congratulations everyone!

How I know we did is I went to https://space.stackexchange.com/ in incognito with chrome and the site completely loads. Also we now have the ability to share answers and questions, (the share button is now visible)

Comment: Yep - [A51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration) says public beta now.

Comment: When I try to share a question, it still gives a Facebook preview saying we're closed Beta.  I guess it just needs to recache or something.